# Multiline JSON without comma separator in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory

I'm trying to read a multi-line JSON file without comma separation using pyspark. I'm not much comfortable with Pyspark. I wanted to do it with simple python but I was getting Memory Errors with 16GB of RAM and file size is 14GB.

Answer (score 0):

Your Multiline JSON file:

```
[
{"name":"Wer","address":"TN"}
{"name":"Yin","address":"KL"}
]
```

Necessary package

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
```

1. Read your json file as text file

```
df_1 = spark.read.text("path/to/file.json")
```

2. Filter unwanted records

```
filter_condition = (col("value") != "[") & (col("value") != "]")
df_2 = df_1.filter(filter_condition)
```

3. Convert JSON strings into StructType format

```
json_schema = "struct<name:string, address:string>"
df_3 = df_2.withColumn("value", from_json("value", json_schema))
```

4. Extract all column out

```
df_3.selectExpr("value.*").show()
```

***Output***

```
+----+-------+
|name|address|
+----+-------+
| Wer|     TN|
| Yin|     KL|
+----+-------+
```